# EEG data, specifically for alzheimer's?

Tags: data-request, medical

Does anyone have any clues on open (or reasonably scrapeable) sources of [EEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) data, especially from Alzheimer's patients?

Comment: for what it's worth, we have now spent a while chasing these data by e-mailing authors of peer-reviewed journals, but have had no luck with about 8-10 queries ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two datasets from the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) related to EEG, but not specific to Alzheimer's patients.

1. The [EEG dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/EEG+Database)

> This data arises from a large study to examine EEG correlates of genetic predisposition to alcoholism.
>
> It contains measurements from 64 electrodes placed on subject's scalps which were sampled at 256 Hz (3.9-msec epoch) for 1 second.

### [image]

2. There is also an [EEG Eye State](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/EEG+Eye+State) related to video analysis of open/closed eyes and EEG measurement.

> All data is from one continuous EEG measurement with the Emotiv EEG Neuroheadset. The duration of the measurement was 117 seconds. The eye state was detected via a camera during the EEG measurement and added later manually to the file after analysing the video frames. '1' indicates the eye-closed and '0' the eye-open state. All values are in chronological order with the first measured value at the top of the data.